# How to calculate average minimal times in Elasticsearch?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Use Elasticsearch version is 5.4.2

I'd like to build an Elasticsearch query to satisfy three conditions.

1. filter by championId
2. get minimal time to buy various item per game
3. calculate avg minimal time to buy each item in all games.

I did 1 and 2. But I could not find solving 3. Is it possible to execute 1 to 3 in the query? Just in case, I will use the result on Laravel 5.4, one of PHP frameworks.

My data format is the following:

```
"_index": "timelines",
"_type": "timeline"
"_source": {
      "gameId": 152735348,
      "participantId": 3,
      "championId": 35,
      "role": "NONE",
      "lane": "JUNGLE",
      "win": 1,
      "itemId": 1036,
      "timestamp": 571200
}
```

My current Elasticsearch query is this

```
GET timelines/_search?size=0&pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "championId":  22 }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
   "games": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "gameId"
     },
     "aggs": {
       "items": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "itemId",
           "order" : { "min_buying_time" : "asc" }
         },
         "aggs": {
           "min_buying_time": {
             "min": {
               "field": "timestamp"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly you should be able to solve this with [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html). More specifically to your use case, the [Avg Bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation.html) should be helpful, check out the example in the documentation, that should be very close to what you need I think.

Something like:

```
"avg_min_buying_time": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "games>min_buying_time" 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sönke, thank you for your advice. I've never heard about the word, "pipeline aggregations".  I am going to check web page you told. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Sönke Liebau said pipeline aggregation is the key, but if you want to count average minimal time of all games per item you should first aggregate by itemID. Following code should help:

```
POST misko/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "championId":  22 }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "items": {
      "terms": {
       "field": "itemId"
     },
     "aggs": {
       "games": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "gameId"
         },
         "aggs": {
           "min_buying_time": {
             "min": {
               "field": "timestamp"
             }
           }
         }
       },
       "avg_min_time": {
         "avg_bucket": {
           "buckets_path": "games>min_buying_time"
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Michal, thank you for your advice. I am going to check 2 ways and which the ways is correct: gameId -> itemId (my way), itemId -> gameId (your way). :)

Comment: No problem. :) Let me know.

Comment: I found your way was correct. My query result contained average of minimal purchase time for all items per match. It did not make sense. But, your query result contained average of minimum purchase time for all games per item. This was what I needed!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you :)